# How to parse through file where filename stored in a variable

Tags: python

I want to parse through a file whose name is stored in a variable.

```py
log_file = archive_log
for line in print log_file:
    print line
```

Here archive_log file contains list of files which have been archived. When I run this code for loop is run on archive_log not on the content of archive_log. So i get output like

```
a
r
c
h
i
v
e
_
l
o
g
```

How can make sure for loop runs on content of a file? Here I need to specify file name in a variable since in future i have to calculate filename based on date.

I am running python 2.4.3. Getting following error :

File "daily_archive.py", 
     line 31 with open(log_file) as f: 
^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This is not the code you have. Please paste the code that is causing described issues.

Comment: Indeed, the code you have posted will not run.

Answer (score 2):

What you have described could be a result of the following:

```py
log_file = 'archive_log'
for line in log_file:
    print line
```

(you print every character in `log_file` string)

Seemingly you want this, however:

```py
log_file = 'archive_log'
with open(log_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Just remember, that the path is relative, and depends on where (from where) you run the code. It is better idea to use absolute paths. You can use eg. [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to get absolute path based on the name of the file (`log_file`, whose value in the example is `'archive_log'`) and path to the script file (`__file__`).

**EDIT**: The following is the solution for Python 2.4 (Python 2.5 [has support for `with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915927/548696)):

```py
log_file = 'archive_log'
try:
    f = open(log_file)
    for line in f:
        print line
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Tadeck. When i am running code as you mentioned i am getting syntax error.

File "daily_archive.py", line 31
    with open(log_file) as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user2501825: What is your version of Python? Also, could you show the syntax error in your question's update? In Python whitespaces matter, but comments in SO do not care about whitespaces & do not have indents.

Comment: @Tadeck: something tells me that your piece of code is better than mine below, but I can't tell why. Another to put it: why `with open('filename') as f` is better than `f = open('filename', 'r') ... f.close()`?

Comment: `with` ensures that the file will get closed even if an exception occurs, so you don't have to explicitly write `try/except` blocks just for that purpose.

Comment: @Tadeck I am running python 2.4.3. Do you want me to put errors in code format?

Comment: @user2501825: Python 2.4 does not have `with` statement. Will update the code to meet your needs.

Comment: @user2501825: Done. If you can, you may wish to switch to Python 2.7+. There is a lot of nice features that come with it. Plus you are missing almost 10 years of development and bugfixes (Python 2.4 was released around November 2004).

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't well posed, but I suppose this is what the OP mean:

```
filename = 'archive_log'
file = open(filename, 'r')

for line in file.readlines()
  print line

file.close()
```

Comment: the other answer should also work. in any case, please accept one of the two.